# localhost UIWebview loads on Simulator but not on Iphone device

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios-simulator, localhost, device

I have a UIWebview that loads a local asp website, it works properly on the Simulator but not on the device. I don't know where is the problem ?

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *index = @"http://192.168.205.146:31021/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:index];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

And

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webViewRef shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simulator is using your Mac's LAN Connection I guess (which has localhost server) and your iPhone might be using your mobile data (i.e 2G or 3G). Check if that is the case. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Is your device on the same network as your mac?

Comment: May be you can try "Internet Sharing" from your Mac from Preferences for your Ethernet connection. And connect to that Wifi in iPhone and see if it loads. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simulator is using your Mac's LAN connection, I guess (which has local-host server) and your iPhone might be using your mobile data (i.e 2G or 3G).

Check if that is the case.

May be you can try "Internet Sharing" from your Mac from Preferences for your Ethernet connection.

And connect to that Wifi in iPhone and see if it loads.

I think this should work and solve your problem of testing on device if you don't have router with your connection.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my mabook is connected via wifi, and with internet sharing I only can share with mac connected via ethernet and then share to wifi. Not wifi -> wifi

Comment: Are you using same Wifi both in iPhone and Macbook?

Comment: @user2037696 Can you try loading the same URL in safari browser in iPhone?